# How to split a pandas df column that has objects?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have this df:

`

```
                                       open       high        low      close                               Date
symbol date
GOOG   2023-01-18 09:30:00-05:00  92.940002  93.449997  92.849998  92.980003  (GOOG, 2023-01-18 09:30:00-05:00)
       2023-01-18 09:35:00-05:00  92.989998  93.070000  92.599998  92.910004  (GOOG, 2023-01-18 09:35:00-05:00)
       2023-01-18 09:40:00-05:00  92.919998  93.035004  92.400002  92.599998  (GOOG, 2023-01-18 09:40:00-05:00)
       2023-01-18 09:45:00-05:00  92.610001  92.699997  92.400002  92.677498  (GOOG, 2023-01-18 09:45:00-05:00)
       2023-01-18 09:50:00-05:00  92.680000  92.855003  92.659203  92.769997  (GOOG, 2023-01-18 09:50:00-05:00)
```

`

and I whant to split the last column df[Date] into symbol and date. That column type is an object.

How can I do this?

The data I have, gives indexed the symbol and date, so when making a new column from the index, it throws both together.

I've tried with this:

`df[['symbol', 'date']]=df.Date.str.split(",",expand = True)`

with error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

and this:

`df['new'] = df['Date'].str.split(',').str[0]`

but both gives error

I've tried with this:

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].tolist()
    df['Date']=pd.DataFrame(df['Date'].tolist, index=df.index)
    df[['Symbol','Dates']] = pd.DataFrame(df['Date'].tolist(),index=df.index)
```

but gives error:

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: "but both gives error"... What error??

Comment: Maybe you have tuples and not strings. The dtype for tuples it's also `'O'`.

Comment: Are you sure `,` appears in each row of `Date` column exactly once?

Comment: I can't manage to make this ...  Could I just extract the date from the index? how?

Comment: problem solved ... I just had to go back and reset the index.